# How to show the input as a list?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have these checklists https://pasteboard.co/J4PepFI.png . how can I show all of them as a list. its only showing the first input. https://pasteboard.co/J4PfgFl.png

```
$origins = get_term_meta( $tagid, 'origin_s', true );

<div class="mt15 ingredient-center-icon">
     <ul><li><?php echo do_shortcode($origins);?></li></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Wordpress reference for `get_term_meta`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/. Third parameter `bool $single = false`, yours is true, is problem?

Comment: what is your `$origins` returning? An array of those checklists or single value? do a `var_dump($origins);` and see what is the returning value... and also getting confused as you are using the value in shortcode... so  i assume the returning value is a shortcode..??

Comment: I don't get the code for starters. You're having a div with an ingredient-center-icon and a list with **one** single entry.. Even if `origin_s` contained 3 shortcodes for all 3 ingredients, why are they in a single `<li>` item?

Comment: @mulquin i chaned it to false now it shows "Array"

Comment: @Bassam Radi good now you can loop through that array and call do_shortcode on them all.

Comment: @SajjadHossainSagor I got this (array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "Plant" [1]=> string(9) "Synthetic" [2]=> string(6) "Animal" }  ) when I added var_dump($origins);
regarding the "shortcode" I am editing a theme php and I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
$origins = get_term_meta( $tagid, 'origin_s', false ); ?>

<div class="mt15 ingredient-center-icon">

  //check if array has any items
  <?php if ( !empty( $origins ) ) : ?>

   <ul>

    <?php foreach ( $origins as $origin ) : ?>

      <li><?php echo do_shortcode( $origin ); ?></li>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

   </ul>

 <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Great it worked. The webpage design brock. I'll try to figure that out.

Comment: maybe because it's missing last div close tag `</div>` check again...